# How do I make an HTML table with too many headers break into multiple tables below?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf, aem

[table spanning multiple PDF pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXGfg.png)

I have an HTML table that I'm rendering on a PDF. Since it is a PDF, I obviously can't make the table scrollable horizontally, but would rather have the entire table break into additional tables below this one, each with the next set of table headers. Right now, the additional headers and their corresponding columns are just being cut off. I know that usually upon page break, tables will repeat the same headers on the next page, but is there any way to have it function the way I need?

Comment: What do you mean you are rendering on PDF ? Do you mean that happens when you try to PRINT html page ?

Comment: @sonic No, I'm using an external PDF generator project developed by one of our teams where sending a POST request to their API endpoint generates a PDF file based on our .pdf.html files in AEM. But besides that point, this is also happening on PDF non-paginated preview for testing purposes. I want the table to break to a new table below after every 13 table headers.

Comment: the only way I can think of is just trying to read and recreate table using javascript.

Comment: Also, you can use Apache FOP (available in AEM) and create a custom service to render the PDF, you will have more control of the output by styling the template that is passed to FOP.